# How to add debouching in button python 2.7

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I have created a button. I want that if someone click repetitively it will execute only once. I disabled the button for 3 seconds .but when the button is normal it executes every click on sequence. I want that in the disabled states click will be ignored. how to do that??

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter,MySQLdb,tkFont,datetime,time,tkMessageBox,socket,os
from datetime import datetime 
class Reception_Qm(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()
    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()
        self.button1 = Tkinter.Button(self, text = my_button,bg="blue",activebackground="yellow",\
                             width=18,font=('Sans','30','bold'),relief=RIDGE,\
                             command = lambda: self.print_token('hello'),fg="white",height=1)
        self.button1.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='NSEW')

    def print_token(self,catagory):
        print "hello"
        self.button1.flash()
        self.button1.config(state=DISABLED)
        time.sleep(3)
        self.button1.config(state=NORMAL)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Reception_Qm(None)
    window.title("Test App")
    window.mainloop()
```

If button is pressed at disabled states also, it will go to print_token function when the button came normal state. I just want to ignore the clicks. I want to ignore the clicks in which between duration is less than 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do a `time.sleep` like that in the middle of an event handler. If you do, you're not returning to the main loop, which means tkinter can't process any events—not even your button-disabling event.

Of course when you finally return, tkinter can start processing things, but at that point, it's got a button enable queued up immediately after the button disable, so the button is only disabled for a tiny fraction of a second.

---

What you need to do is split the second half of the function off into a separate function, ask tkinter to run that function for you in 3 seconds, and then return immediately:

```
def print_token(self,catagory):
    print "hello"
    self.button1.flash()
    self.button1.config(state=DISABLED)
    self.after(3000, lambda: self.button1.config(state=NORMAL))
```